# How to continue running after correcting values when a bug occurs in ipython notebook debugging?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, pdb, ipdb

For example,

```
def power(x, n):
    res = 1
    for i in range(n):
        res *= x
    return res
power('10',5)
```

Then, it will raise the error as follows.

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Now, I try to use `%debug` in the new notebook cell to debug.

```
ipdb> x = int(10)
ipdb> c
```

However, in `%debug`, if I use `c` which means `continue` in `ipdb`, it can't continue to run with changed value `x`.

So, I wonder if there is any method to correct the value of a variable while debugging and continue to run.

---

Update：

This is just an example.

In fact, I want to run the code for a long time in some cases, and an error occurs midway. I want to correct the error and try to continue to run the code. You know, simply re-running can take a long time.

Comment: Have you considered using try/except?

Answer (score 1):

Check the below solutions:

`x` value should not be `str` type

Use `power(10,5)` instead of `power('10',5)`

OR

Convert value of `x` in the code:

```
def power(x, n):
    res = 1
    for i in range(n):
        res *= int(x)
    return res
print(power('10',5))
```

Comment: I updated my needs. Actually, I want to know how to debug effectively in debug mode.